# sprites - cache issue - especially on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, caching, sprite

I have the following problem.

We have a site. I changed some sprites to make it look cooler. The thing is that we already have users and there is a big chance that their browser have the old images cached. Is there anyway to force a new request to images from them?

Note: On firefox (default settings) after some refreshes the new sprites are requested but seems like chrome (default settings) just doesn't request them unless you explicitly clear cache.

Another Note: One way would be to rename the sprites but this also means that we have to find them in css files and rename there also, etc. etc. etc.

Have a great day and ty for help.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but what if you force the browser to load the new CSS by adding a query string? For example "style.css?v=1.0". Wouldn't that force the browser to load the new images as well?

Comment: Don't think so... inside is still old name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to add a random number onto the end of the image name e.g.

```
.mybackground {
    background-image:url(../images/background.jpg?16549);
}
```

If you could make the number random every time the page is loaded via some JS or PHP or whatever that would work for you. YOu could maybe take the images out of your stylesheet and place then in a style tag in your header include or whatever so that you can do the random number bit to them. (Not sure if you could do directly into the stylesheet)

Comment: Sounds easy and should fix it.

Comment: what is the point of a sprite then? The idea of a sprite is to reduce requests to the server, and cache the image for browsing your website faster. If you add a query to your link, the browser won't cache it, and it will be reloaded every time.

Comment: @Dan - The point of a sprite is to reduce the amount of http requests coming from lots of individual images. So even though with the random number you're calling the sprite every time it is still achieving its primary objective of reducing http requests.

Comment: Also I can make a function to add random number only for a few hours/days after I update a sprite. That should is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming sounds more feasible. You can most likely automate it with (shell)scripts so it shouldn't be a too bad.

Comment: Yes but I'm actually searching for a general solution... It's the 3rd time we have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Most IDE have a feature to find and replace in multiple files, you can use it to change the path to the sprite in the CSS files. Your best bet, is to give a new name for the new image for now.

As for later on, I suggest looking at your [caching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) and [expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) headers of your web sever. (These are links to the Apache documentation, if your web server isn't apache, it would be same idea, but requires different implementation.)